# How to run cv_bridge?

Tags: catkin, cv-bridge, cmake, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi , i want to run cv_bridge, so i refer to [Converting between ROS images and OpenCV images (C++)](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages) i did every thing were told at" An example ROS node" at the end i added the commad below to the end of CMakelist.txt and after that run `catkin_make`

```
add_executable(image_converter src/image_converter.cpp)
target_link_libraries(image_converter ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(image_converter beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)
```

but i have 2 problems :

1. when i run catkin_make i receive this error :

   CMake Error: Error in cmake code at
   /home/fatima/catkin_ws3/src/beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:135:
   Parse error.  Expected a command name, got unquoted argument with text "/add_executable".
2. and if it can be run , how to run image_converter file and how to see the result of cv_bridge ?

hi thnks for reply , this is my CMakelists: i dont know is it true for cv_bridge or not?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(beginner_tutorials)


find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cv_bridge
  image_transport
  roscpp
  rospy
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
genmsg message_generation
)

add_message_files(FILES Num.msg )
add_service_files(FILES AddTwoInts.srv)



 generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
sensor_msgs
cv_bridge
roscpp
std_msgs
image_transport
 )
generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)
catkin_package( INCLUDE_DIRS include
 LIBRARIES ${beginner_tutorials} CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime roscpp nodelet)
catkin_package(  )


include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
catkin_package()
add_library()/add_executable()/target_link_libraries(
add_library(beginner_tutorials
  src/${PROJECT_NAME}/beginner_tutorials.cpp
 )


add_dependencies(beginner_tutorials ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})


add_dependencies(beginner_tutorials_node ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})


 target_link_libraries(beginner_tutorials_node
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
 )

add_executable(image_converter src/image_converter.cpp)
target_link_libraries(image_converter ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(image_converter beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)
```

And now after fixing the last problem i have again another problem with generate_messages :
CMakeLists :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(beginner_tutorials)


find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cv_bridge
  image_transport
  roscpp
  rospy
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
genmsg message_generation
)

################################################
## Declare ROS messages, services and actions ##
################################################


## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
 
add_message_files(FILES Num.msg )
add_service_files(FILES AddTwoInts.srv)


## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
# add_service_files(
#   FILES
#   Service1.srv
#   Service2.srv
# )

## Generate actions in the 'action' folder
# add_action_files(
#   FILES
#   Action1.action
#   Action2.action
# )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
 generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
sensor_msgs
cv_bridge
roscpp
std_msgs
image_transport
#  sensor_msgs#   std_msgs
 )
##generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)
catkin_package( INCLUDE_DIRS include
 LIBRARIES ${beginner_tutorials} CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime roscpp nodelet)

# include_directories(include)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
catkin_package()
##add_library()/add_executable()/target_link_libraries()
## Declare a C++ library
add_library(beginner_tutorials
  src/${PROJECT_NAME}/beginner_tutorials.cpp
 )

## Add cmake target dependencies of the library
## as an example, code may need to be generated before libraries
## either from message generation or dynamic reconfigure
add_dependencies(beginner_tutorials ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Declare a C++ executable
# add_executable(beginner_tutorials_node src/beginner_tutorials_node.cpp)

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable
## same as for the library above
add_dependencies(beginner_tutorials_node ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
 target_link_libraries(beginner_tutorials_node
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
 )

## Add gtest based cpp test target and link libraries
# catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}-test test/test_beginner_tutorials.cpp)
# if(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}-test)
#   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-test ${PROJECT_NAME})
# endif()

## Add folders to be run by python nosetests
# catkin_add_nosetests(test)
add_executable(image_converter src/image_converter.cpp)
target_link_libraries(image_converter ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(image_converter beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)
```

and this is my catkin_make Error :

```
Base path: /home/fatima/catkin_ws3
Source space: /home/fatima/catkin_ws3/src
Build space: /home/fatima/catkin_ws3/build
Devel space: /home/fatima/catkin_ws3/devel
Install space: /home/fatima/catkin_ws3/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/fatima/catkin_ws3/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/fatima/catkin_ws3/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/indigo
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/fatima/catkin_ws3/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.16
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - beginner_tutorials
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'beginner_tutorials'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(beginner_tutorials)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:268 (message):
  Could not find 'share/cv_bridge/cmake/cv_bridge-msg-paths.cmake' (searched
  in '/home/fatima/catkin_ws3/devel;/opt/ros/indigo').
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:75 (generate_messages)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/fatima/catkin_ws3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/fatima/catkin_ws3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223107/how-to-run-cv_bridge?/) by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2015-12-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on 2015-12-27**:
Is the code you are trying to compile in the beginner_tutorials package or in another? Because it seems to me that the problem is with the beginner_tutorials package... Just a thought...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you have a syntax error in your CMakeLists.txt file, in part of the file that you haven't included in your answer.

Without the rest of your CMakeLists.txt it's hard to say what is wrong, but perhaps one of the previous cmake commands is missing a closing parenthesis.

**UPDATE**

You should remove or comment this line:

```
add_library()/add_executable()/target_link_libraries()
```

It doesn't do anything, and the `/` characters are a syntax error.

**UPDATE**

The error `Could not find 'share/cv_bridge/cmake/cv_bridge-msg-paths.cmake'`  suggests that there's something wrong with your message dependencies; I think it can't find messages for `cv_bridge`

Do your messages depend on any messages from cv_bridge? Otherwise, I would suggest you remove cv_bridge as a dependency in `generate_messages()`

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-12-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-29**:
thank you so much , i did it and now i have another problem i edited my question above and put my error and cmakelists again please help thank you

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-29**:
hi , thanks so much ,  i have done every thing as told in this [link](http:///cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages) , and i want to `Convert between ROS images and OpenCV images (C++)` is there ant thing i should do for finding messages for `cv_bridge` ?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-12-29**:
I'm going to ask again: "Do your messages depend on any messages from cv_bridge?"

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-12-31**:
I don't think there are any messages in cv_bridge. Perhaps it should be removed from the `generate_messages()` call?